# get time difference between a ISO date and date now?

Tags: javascript, date

So i am trying to get how many seconds there between a ISO date and current time.

My attempt looks like this:

```
var date = new Date('2018-01-20T15:45:16.698Z').getTime();
var now = Date.now();
var timeLeft = date - now;
var timeLeftInSeconds = Math.floor(timeLeft/ 1000);
```

but i am getting an incorrect difference and i assume it becuase that ISO dates are UTC while Date.now() are local time. but now sure how to work around this issue?

Comment: What is the result you are getting? The code is working in my case.

Comment: Date.now() is UTC too, all Dates are. It's timestamps (i.e. dates formatted as strings) that have time zones.